# An example of a formula with infinite Morley Rank

Tags: logic, model-theory

Given a Theory and a Model, you can define the [Morley Rank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morley_rank) of formulas with parameters from the model.

I'd like you to give me an example of a formula (with theory and model) with infinite Morley Rank.

In the linked page of Wiki, there's an example of it, but I can't seem to be able to prove it formally.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy infinite rank is not the same of rank $\alpha$ with $\alpha$ an infinite ordinal..

Comment: Yes, if a theory or formula has Morley Rank $\infty$, this means that the rank of the formula is greater than the every ordinal. But the claim in the wikipedia article that the theory of $(\omega^\alpha,<)$ has rank $\alpha$ is nonsense. This theory has the order property, and every unstable theory has Morley Rank $\infty$. I'm going to remove the claim from the article.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple one.

In the theory $Th(\mathbb{Q},<)$ the formula $x=x$ has rank $\infty$.

First, let $a^1_n,a^2_n$ be an infinite sequence of 2-tuples of $\mathbb{Q}$ where $a^1_n < a^2_n <a^1_{n+1}<a^2_{n+1+}$.

Now, consider the formula (with parameters) $\varphi_n(x)\equiv (a^1_n <x<a^2_n)$. Note that $\varphi_n(\mathbb{Q})=\aleph_0$ as well as $\varphi_n(\mathbb{Q})\cap\varphi_m(\mathbb{Q})=\emptyset$ for $n \neq m$. Finally, realizing that each $\varphi_n(\mathbb{Q})\cong \mathbb{Q}$, we can repeat the processes indefinitely, and so we can construct arbitrarily large trees.

However, since $|\mathbb{Q}|=\aleph_0$, the argument above only works morally. What you actually do is just build arbitrarily large trees. You can do this by just picking large saturated models (say of size $\kappa$) and doing exactly the same above. You will construct a tree of size $\kappa$.

Therefore, the rank of $x=x$ has unbounded ($\infty$) rank in $(\mathbb{Q},<)$.

Comment: Simple one, not simply one. I assume. :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Haha, I haven't had my coffee yet...

Comment: The thing I don't understand is this: is it true that given $A,B$ isomorphic models, then they have the same Morley Rank? And given two $\omega$-saturated models (even with different cardinality), is it true that they have the same Morley Rank?

Comment: Morely Rank is supposed to be used in the context of theories, not models. Clearly, you cannot build a tree of size $2^{\aleph_0}$ out of $(\mathbb{Q}.<)$, but we can find a model $\mathfrak{B} \equiv (\mathbb{Q},<)$, such that we can.